# Amazon EC2 cluster setup

Tags: amazon-ec2, hdfs

I am working on a HDFS high availability project.

I have configured Hadoop on one Amazon EC2 instance. It is small instance (AMI: Ubuntu server)

I want to form a cluster of EC2 instances. So, i am thinking of replicating the same machine. Does anybody have a clue about how to duplicate this instance on another instance of EC2. If yes, please share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your instance is EBS backed, you can make a snapshot and then run as many instance as you want from it.

Comment: While creating an instance i did not pay attention to  back it with EBS. Is it possible now to back it with EBS?

Comment: I can see an EBS volume with capcity 8GiB.. Does that mean this instance is EBS backed? if so, how can we make a snapshot of it and then run?

Comment: If you didn't created EBS volume for some other reason - it do mean youj instance is EBS backet. Go to the left hand menu and find snapshot. But rember - you instance will be restarted

Comment: Thanks David. This link is good source of information for me.